# is it needed to add init-method in Sprint configuration file if there is nothing to initialize

Tags: java, spring, soap

I am new to Java. I have below java class:-

```
@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use = SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL)
public class ABC extends AbstractWebService {

    protected ClassNameForService classNameForService;

    public void init() {
    }

    @WebMethod
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    @GET
    /**
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public String test(
        @WebParam(partName = "sessionID")
        @QueryParam("sessionID") String sessionID
    ) throws UserNotDefinedException
    {
    // does something here
    }
    
}
```

and below is my spring configuration file

```
 <bean id=”org.testproject.webservices.ABC class=”org.testproject.webservices.ABC init-method=”init” parent=”org.testproject.webservices.AbstractWebService”>
        <property name=classNameForService ref=”org.testproject.service.gb.ClassNameForService/>
    </bean>
```

So do we need `init-method=”init”` here? Can I remove `init-method=”init”` from configuration as well as init method from class, Is it a standard practice?

Answer (score 1):

You do NOT have to specify an init method (or destroy method for that matter).  I think it's worth noting that you ask if it's standard practice, I believe the standard practice has moved away from the XML configuration to an annotation-driven approach but for the purpose of your question, it is standard practice to not include an init method when it is not needed.

The `init-method` is akin to adding a `@PostContstruct` annotated method on annotation declared beans.